# Insertar una fecha en mysql con formato 15 nov 20

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Tengo un problema al intentar registrar una fecha en una tabla
que tiene dos columnas id, y fecha que es de tipo datetime

deseo insertar en el campo fecha un valor igual a "15 ene 20" en vez del "15-01-20"
utilizo esta sentencia que es util pero solo me acepta colocar los meses en ingles y necesito insertarlo en español es decir para insertar enero tendria que colocar "jan" en vez de "ene"

> insert into prueba values(null,str_to_date('15 dic 19', '%d %b %y'));

tambien

> SET lc_time_names = 'es_PE';

utilizo esa sentencia que me ayudo para realizar los select y cambia el idioma de los meses pero al momento de insertar me sigue saliendo error alguien podria ayudarme gracias

Comment: Al margen de las respuestas recibidas me parece un error de planteamiento el pensar en almacenar formateadas las fechas en tu bd, eso debería estar a nivel de la vista, considera que si en algún momento las requieres en 1 o N formatos distintos estarás de todos modos modificando el valor almacenado, puedes mejor guardar la marca de tiempo completa y ya en tus selects dar el formato necesario

Comment: Si el campo es datetime no tiene sentido lo que tratas de hacer. Como bien te indicó @BetaM . El formato lo debes dar al mostrarlo. Incluso hay funciones de formato para realizar las consultas cuando has guardado correctamente. Si eso no te sirve, debes pensar en otro tipo de campo (texto) y después **lidiar con código** el mantenimiento de las fechas

Comment: no deseo guardar ese formato en la base de datos, lo que estoy haciendo es subir varios archivos que tendran un campo con ese formato '15 DIC 20' y en la base de datos si se guardara como 15-12-20

Answer (score 2):

**Lo que intentas hacer es imposible:**

para Mysql el unico formato de Fechas son los siguientes:

```
Data Type   “Zero” Value
DATE        '0000-00-00'
TIME        '00:00:00'
DATETIME    '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
TIMESTAMP   '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
YEAR        0000
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

**La solución**

guardar en el formato aceptado por Mysql y al momento de mostrar por pantalla formatear la fecha:

Ejemplo el PHP:

```
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$myDateTime = new DateTime('2016-03-21 13:14', $gmtTimezone);
echo $myDateTime->format('r');
```

salida:

```
Mon, 21 Mar 2016 13:14:00 +0000.
```

**Deberás adaptar esto a tu lenguaje de backend ya que no indicaste cual usas.**

Comment: pero yo logre registrar con esta linea

insert into prueba values(null,str_to_date('15 dic 19', '%d %b %y'));